# Selecting elements whose attribute begins with something in XPath

Tags: java, html, xhtml, xpath

As the title says, is it possible to select elements in XPath that only begin with a certain string, but perhaps do not end with the same?

For example there are 3 anchor elements:

```
<a href="buy.php/onething"></a><a href="buy.php/twothing"></a><a href="sell.php/anotherthing"></a>
```

I only want to get anchor elements that begin with 'buy.php/'. I don't think the following will work, will it:

```
getByXPath("//a[@href='buy.php/']")
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 174, accepted):

`//a[starts-with(@href, 'buy.php/')]`

http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XSLTreference/Output/function_starts-with.html

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is exactly the correct syntax but you probably want to use the fn:contains xpath function.  Other useful functions you can find here:

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string

getByXPath("//a[fn:contains(@href/text(), 'buy.php/')]")

Comment: above link is dead but here's another function reference that isn't: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions