# Finding element in Python by xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, partial

I am trying to click on an item whose xpath is:

```
//*[@id="single-71048602500"]/div[2]/div[1]
```

There are more elements that start with `//*[@id="single"]`, and the number changes each time the page loads. So the only specific bits are the combination of "single" and `/div[2]/div[1].`

The CSS_selector has the number as well, so it is of no use.

**What would the code to select the element be?**

I'm using Python and Selenium.

Comment: Can I get the application url?Also let me know which element you wanted to click.

Comment: show your html source

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting elements whose attribute begins with something in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301898/selecting-elements-whose-attribute-begins-with-something-in-xpath)

Comment: Try this xpath and let me know how it goes ```(//*[contains(@id="single")]/div[2]/div[1])[index of an element ]```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this xpath and let me know how it goes.

`(//*[contains(@id,"single")]/div[2]/div[1])[index of an element ]`

The below xpath will help you to find all the element which is contains  id values as single

`//*[contains(@id,"single")]/div[2]/div[1]`

Comment: Yosuva A, thanks for your help. Works perfectly. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here, I am assuming that you want to click all the elements that has the combination of "single" and /div[2]/div[1].

First, try to get all the elements from the required element's parent element.Now you'd be left with list of WebElements.iterate through all elements and click elements whose id starts with single.

```
sd = mainpage.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id]') #parent webelement
for i in sd:

        if str(i.get_attribute('id')).startswith("single"):

             j = i.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="{}"]/div[2]/div[1]'.format(i.get_attribute('id')))
             j.click()
```

Comment: `find_elements_by_xpath("//*[starts-with(@id, 'single')]/div[2]/div[1]")` should immediately find the desired elements

Comment: Adrian W, thanks, perfect. I didn't know you could add /div[2] etc to the end of the starts with stuff. Brill, thanks again.