# Replace the href value of qualifying <a>'s using the tag's visible text

Tags: php, replace, html-parsing, anchor, href

I have a big string with a lot of URLs, I need to replace the URLs that match:

```
<a href="../plugins/re_records/somefile.php?page=something&id=X">important_name</a>
```

(where `X` is an any integer and `important_name` is any string) with:

```
<a href="/map/important_name">important_name</a>
```

I'm using `preg_match_all()` to match all URLs:

```
preg_match_all('/\/plugins\/re\_records\/somefile\.php\?page\=something\&id\=*(\d+)/', $bigString, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

The problem is that I don't understand how to get the `important_name` from the hyperlink's visible text to become part of the new url after the URL match.

Is it a good idea to use `preg_match_all()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regex. Use [`DOMDocument`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). They are specifically made to parse HTML/XML documents.

Get all anchor tag elements, check for value in `href` attribute and change the attribute accordingly using `setAttribute()` method.

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // to disable warnings if HTML is not well formed 
$o = new DOMDocument();
$o->loadHTML('<a href="../plugins/re_records/somefile.php?page=something&id=45">important_name</a>');

foreach($o->getElementsByTagName('a') as $anchor_tag){
    $href = $anchor_tag->getAttribute('href');
    if(strpos($href,'/plugins/re_records/somefile.php?page=something&id=') !== false){
        $anchor_tag->setAttribute('href','/map/'.$anchor_tag->nodeValue);
    }
}

echo $o->saveHTML();
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/5GPXA

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This solves my problem and I think that is the most clean and beautiful way, but unfortunately (and I know it's silly), this adds the <html> and <body> tags, is there a way (without more code) to avoid that? Maybe some DOMDocument method?

Comment: Well, you can use str_replace to trim off those.

Comment: Yes, I have been seeing that this has been a problem for a long time. I can use a lot of things to remove them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to get the matched `important_name`?

Then just add parentheses around it and you can get it in the `$matches`.

```php
<?php
$s = '<a href="../plugins/re_records/somefile.php?page=something&id=123">important_name</a>';

preg_match_all('/\<a href\=\"\.\.\/plugins\/re\_records\/somefile\.php\?page\=something\&id\=*(\d+)\"\>(.*?)\<\/a\>/', $s, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

var_dump($matches[2][0][0])
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Definitely get into the habit of parsing HTML with a legitimate DOM parser.  Using regex will set you up for headaches eventually.  When a DOM parser fails you, **then** consider using regex.
- I prefer to filter the parsed document with XPath because the expressions can be very power and flexible.
- To silence any warnings when loading your string into DOMDocument, call `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);`.  This will silence any warnings.
- Use the [`LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` flags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php) to omit the `<DOCTYPE>`, `<HTML>`, and `<BODY>` tags that you don't want/need.
- [`starts-with()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301944/2943403) will do nicely since you are not trying to extract the id number from the end of the querystring.
- Don't be put off by the encoded `&` in the output -- [it's a good thing / part of a more modern standard](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/26640/12352).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ns7hk))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div>
    <p> some text <a href="../plugins/re_records/somefile.php?page=something&id=345">find_me_1</a></p>
    <br>
    <a href="../plugins/re_records/somefile.php?page=something&id=99">find_me_2</a>
    <div>
        <div>
            <a href="example.com?page=something&id=55">don't even think about it!</a>
            <a href="../plugins/re_records/somefile.php?page=something&id=90210">find_me_3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
HTML;

$hrefStartsWith = '../plugins/re_records/somefile.php?page=something&id=';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query("//a[starts-with(@href, '$hrefStartsWith')]") as $a) {
    $a->setAttribute('href', '/map/' . $a->nodeValue);
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<div>
    <p> some text <a href="/map/find_me_1">find_me_1</a></p>
    <br>
    <a href="/map/find_me_2">find_me_2</a>
    <div>
        <div>
            <a href="example.com?page=something&amp;id=55">don't even think about it!</a>
            <a href="/map/find_me_3">find_me_3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```